# Searching for a book written for medical school freshmen

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to find a certain book I first ran into many years ago but unfortunately forgot the name of.

As far as I recall, the book targeted medical school freshmen. No, it's **not** [*How to Be Pre-Med: A Harvard MD's Medical School Preparation Guide for Students and Parents* by Suzanne M. Miller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0688175899). The book I'm searching for is not a "practical" guidebook on details like application procedures, admission requirements etc. but rather about giving advice to new students on both how to deal with medical studies and university life in general. I think it was about how to live on your own, how to plan your studies, how to manage relationships (from making normal friends to having safe sex with your partner), how to balance/prioritize/enjoy different aspects of school life, stuff like that.

The book was published no later than 2013, written by an American female (sorry I forgot her name, but I think she was working at Harvard Medical School when she wrote the book).

Thanks!